# Three.js keep ratio and position on resize canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, render

I have a div contain a three.js canvas. I would like keep the ratio and position of content canvas when the size of the canvas is changed.

[image]

I have try:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}
```

but this work on window resize only and not on canvas resize. I have too modified this code whit canvas width and height but not working.

Comment: I have found a solution: Add a style ´width:100%´ on the canvas. Work perfect!

Comment: I have the same issue, but making the container `width 100%` wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event that will trigger when you will resize your canvas, so you would probably want to handle canvas resizing with js and not css. This event will trigger your `onWindowResize` function and this would solve your issue.